# Simulating Apple Watch background push notifications PushNotificationPayload.apns

Tags: apple-push-notifications, watchkit

I can successfully use the `PushNotificationPayload.apns` file to simulate a push notification in the simulator but it simulates a foreground `UIUserNotificationActionBehaviorDefault` notification.

How can I simulate a background notification with an action behavior of `UIUserNotificationActionBehaviorTextInput`?